Power Automate - Onedrive Find Files in Folder retrieves empty body
I have a flow with an action that creates a JSON file in a specific folder (this is inside a For Each loop). After the loop, I have another action, Find Files in Folder (OneDrive), where I pass the name of the JSON file that was created and the folder where it should search as parameters. The output of this action returns a Body = []. In other words, it's empty.

The component highlighted in yellow is returning Body = empty. I added a "List Files in Folder" component, which correctly returns that the file exists. What I expect to see is that the "Find JSON in Folder" component returns an output that I can use in "Get file content 1". In the "Get File Content 1" component, I am passing the file ID that should be returned by the output of "Find JSON in Folder".
Upon checking, I see that the file was successfully created in the first step, but for some reason, it is not found.
What could be the problem?
I have already made sure that the file is created correctly before using the search option.

can you show us what you tried that is not working?

also what you expect to see?
